# Shoes GUI won't open at all

Tags: ruby, windows, shoes

I've built a small application with shoes, running it on my Win 10 64 bit Laptop is not a problem at all, everything works fine. I tried to install shoes at my station (Win 10, 64 bit too), installation process is not a problem, command-line based stuff with the cshoes.exe (for example installing gems) works without any problem, but I cant start the shoes.exe at all, it appears in the task-manager, but there is no Gui and no Icon shown in the taskbar. When I try to start applications written with Shoes there is an empty windows popping up, but its just frozen and crashes as soon as its open. It is not a bundled app but a simple .rb file that I want to run with the installed shoes.exe. I tried it with compability mode for the shoes.exe, tried compability with win7 and win XP but it won't work. Did anyone experience this before and is there a solution for this?
Greetings, rtuz2th

Comment: application with shoes??

Comment: Would you be willing to post your source code?

Comment: Hi,
source Code is irrelevant, even tried it with something like
     Shoes.app { button("Click me!") { alert("Good job.") } }
but it did not work. I reinstalled shoes several times and restarted machine, when I did this about five times it worked.. Don't ask me why
@folibis: Shoes is a graphics toolkit for ruby

Comment: Which shoes version are you using?